# RequireJS and Handlebars - Handlebars is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Require JS and Handlebars inside a j Query plugin but all I get is "Handlebars is undefined". Handlebars is being loaded properly.

My config:

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "static/js/lib",
   paths: {
      "jquery": "jquery-1.10.2.min",
      "handlebars": "handlebars-v3.0.1",
   },
   shim: {
      "jquery.myplugin": {
         deps: ["handlebars"]
      }
   }
});
```

And requiring the plugin:

```
require(["jquery"], function(){

   if( $('[data-init="myplugin"]').size() > 0 ){
      require(["jquery.myplugin"], function(){
         $(function(){
            Handlebars.compile("<a></a>"); // This throws Handlebars is undefined
         });
         $('[data-init="myplugin"]').myplugin();

      });
   }

});
```

Then I would like to use Handlebars inside the plugin. How can I pass Handlebars to my plugin so I can compile template? (in script tags)

Comment: test in console require('handlebars').compile("<a></a>") is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set handlebars as a dependency if you want it to be defined. For example you could change the first line to be:

```
require(["jquery", "handlebars"], function($, Handlebars){
```

Also, if the file where `jquery.myplugin` is made or editable by you, you should modify it to call `define()` instead of using the shim config. If that's not an option, you could probably add jquery as a dependency too to the shim config. Then you can only have a single require call that has all three dependencies.